# Runtime Exception Nativescript-Angular

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am a newbie to nativescript-angular though I exhibit proficiency in Angular2 owing to a number of developed applications.

I am using this [sidedrawer](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-angular-drawer-template) which comes with home, about, and contact component.

In addition I created a search component that will be responsible for accepting user input and search specific search engines for the search term.

I successfully ran my nativescript app on an android connected device (Lollipop) however I get:

1. D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
2. When I navigate to the search component, the search component stays for a couple of seconds (say 2 seconds) and returns to the home component by itself.

The following highlights my configurations

Android build tools: 25.0.0
Typescript: 2.0.9
The latest nativescript modules
What I have done so far (removed and reinstall):

node_modules
hooks
platform android

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 mins 10.37 secs
Project successfully built
Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'I7LVZ97L99999999'.
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1100): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;                    
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1230): Got unexpected exception:      
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject    
D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative
(Native Method)
D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at   
com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:865)
D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at 
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:730)
D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at 
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:716)
D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at 
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:697)
D/AccessibilityManager(17308): at 
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:687)
JS: Angular 2 is running in the development mode. 
Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1100): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1230): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
JS: result: 0
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1230): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1100): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1230): Got unexpected exception: 
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;   
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1100): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject      
D/dxoptimizer.hcq( 1230): Got unexpected exception:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;  
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject

******SEARCH COMPONENT *********


export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

private text: string = 'Search Page';
private resultList: Array; //Holds the returned search results
private metaData: any; //Holds data necessary for paginating search results
private query: string;
private isLoading: boolean;
private database: any;
private isEditing: boolean;

constructor( private location: Location,private page: Page,private
routerExtensions: RouterExtensions, private webService: WebService){   
this.isLoading = false;
this.query = "";
this.resultList = [];
//this.resultList = JSON.parse(ApplicationSettings.getString("resultList","
[]"));
console.log("result: "+this.resultList.length);

//Called on navigate back because constructor does not get called
on navigate back
//this.location.subscribe((path)=>{
//this.resultList = JSON.parse(ApplicationSettings.getString
("resultList"," []"));
//});
}
ngOnInit(){

  this.isEditing = true;
}

navBack(){
this.hideKeyboard();
this.routerExtensions.backToPreviousPage();
}

hideKeyboard(){
let searchBar = this.page.getViewById("searchBox");
setTimeout(function(){
searchBar.dismissSoftInput();
}, 100);
}
search(){

//var textview: TextView = <TextView> args.object;
//if(isAndroid){
//textview.android.clearFocus();
//}
this.hideKeyboard();
this.isLoading = true;
this.text = "searching"; 

 permissions.requestPermission("android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET"
 ,"INTERNET PERMISSION NEEDED")
       .then(()=>{
                  this.webService
                      .googleSearch(this.query)
                      .subscribe( (resp:Response) => {
                                      this.resultList = resp.json().items;

                                      console.log(this.resultList);

                                      this.metaData = resp.json().queries;

                                      console.log(this.metaData);
                                      this.text = "Finished Searching!!!";
                                      this.isLoading = false;
                                      this.isEditing = false;
                                     },
                            err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                             }
                         );
       })
       .catch(()=>{
         this.text = "No Permissions";
       })
}

onCancel(){
this.query = "";
this.navBack();
}

onItemTap(){

ApplicationSettings.setString("resultList",JSON.stringify(this.resultList));
//Navigate to details view
}
}
```